# Wubi/Ubuntu dual boot still appears after windows reinstallation

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, wubi

I have used wubi before so that i could use ubuntu, but recently i reset and reinstalled windows and my ubuntu dual boot is there on start up, when i try to run it it comes up with a bios looking screen which says windows is installed improperly, this is likely because when i reinstalled windows it removed the most of the ubuntu files. This is a problem because when i try to install wubi now it says some of the files already exist and i get a bunch of grub errors. i have tried looking at partitions and it doesnt show anything but my main drive and my system partition, i have tried other versions of ubuntu and that also didnt work, if you could let me know what else i can try that would be appreciated :)

Comment: Which version of Windows did you install? I don't think WUBI works in Windows 10 or with secure boot. WUBI does not use real partitions. It creates a huge file within Windows partition and use it as a virtual partition. You may have to change the bootloader settings used by WUBI. Try [something like this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/)

Comment: im on windows version 1903

Comment: thanks this worked but now i have an issue with the nouveau drivers where it just goes to a terminal screen and then says no input detected and you cant do anything from there, my inputs just dont matter